# Wired netwok / netplan is missing

Tags: networking, mount, internet, ethernet

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 in my VM. Until today, I was able to access the internet on my Ubuntu machine, but all of a sudden I see there is no wired network option available in settings. And also there is no Netplan option available in `/etc`.

Please, someone, guide me on how to get back the wired network option in my Ubuntu VM. I have checked the setting in my VM for the network, and it is all fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 and configured Hyper-V and installed Ubuntu on it.

After researching a lot on the internet about my problem I did not get any resolution, hence I reinstall the Ubuntu, and when I again modified the /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml I got the same issue again.

So the solution for my problem was to write a new .yaml file with the content like,

network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager

and save the file by name 01-network-manager-all.yaml .

The file location has to be /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
and restart the VM.